# Commontator gem username

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm using the Commontator gem and it's working fine.  Unfortunately, the logged in user who adds a comment shows up as Anonymous.  How do I use the username in my user model for Commontator?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/lml/commontator/wiki/Custom-username-on-comments :

If you are creating a comment and see "Anonymous" as the commentor and would like to customize what is displayed there ie. "Frank" or "example@gmail.com" you can customize that by going into the config/initializers/commontator.rb file and changing this line:

```
config.user_name_proc = lambda { |user| I18n.t('commontator.anonymous') }
```

For instance, if you have a 'full_name' method, you could change the above to:

```
config.user_name_proc = lambda { |user| user.full_name }
```